# Unable to save anything to CD, disc mounts as Read-Only

Tags: cd, burning, brasero, k3b

I have recently upgrade to Ubuntu 13.04 64 bits and now I can't save nothing to CD.
The CD is mounted automatically when I introduce a CD-ROM but in gnome-disks shows:
[image: gnome-disks screenshot]

```
$ dmesg | grep sr0
  sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 48x/48x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
  sr 18:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
  sr 18:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 

$ ll /dev/sr0
brw-rw----+ 1 root cdrom 11, 0 may  3 17:23 /dev/sr0
```

When I use Brasero or K3B, apparently they save the files to CD but when I mount the used CD-ROM, it contains nothing.
For example, I try to create an audio CD with several MP3 files and this is the output of K3b: [debug output of k3b](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5629492/)

Answer (score 0):

The debug output you have provided from k3b shows a perfectly functional run of cdrecord to create an audio cd, with no error whatsoever.

The read-only in the GUI properties of the drive refers only to the capabilities of the filesystem of the CD-ROM (remember that the data on cd-rom is composed and written once, never to be written again).  It is not saying that the drive is read-only, just that the files on the drive are read-only.

I hope that helps...